# Can we pass functor as an argument to another functor?

Tags: ocaml

I want to know if we can have a local module inside the module. This can be achieved if a functor can be passed as an argument to another functor. But I am not sure if we can do that.

My apologies if this is a vague question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to define higher-order functors. Here is a simple example of a functor that applies its first argument to its second argument:

```
module App (F : functor (X: sig end) -> sig end) (X: sig end) = F (X)
```

This is however unrelated to the question of having local modules, which are very straightforward and do not require functors. The following example defines a submodule B that remains private to A:

```
module A : (sig val g : unit -> unit end) = struct
  module B = struct
    let f () = print_endline "Hello"
  end
  let g = B.f
end

let () = A.g ()    (* valid, prints Hello *)
let () = A.B.f ()  (* invalid *)
```